# i want to set the custom stacking button class's button text differently for each ViewController

Tags: swift

I set the custom `stackButtonView` Like this.
I want to use this class to the another class with changing buttonText context.

["1","2","3","4"] >> ["a","b","c","d"]

I thought buttonText set to global property . Am I right? ..

class kindsButtonView: UIView{

```
 //...
let buttonText: [String] = [
                  "1","2","3","4"
            ]
public func addButtonsToStackView() {
        
         
    let numberOfButtons = buttonText.count
    
    let column = 2
    let row: Int
    
    if numberOfButtons % column != 0 {
        row = (numberOfButtons / column) + 1
    } else {
        row = numberOfButtons / column
    }
    
    for i in 0 ..< row {
        
        let horizontalSv = UIStackView()
        horizontalSv.axis = .horizontal
        //horizontalSv.alignment = .fill

        horizontalSv.distribution = .fillEqually
        horizontalSv.spacing = 8
        
        for j in 0 ..< column {
            if buttonText.count  == i*column + j {
                let hideButton = SurveyButton()
                // make tranparant !
                hideButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
                hideButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
                hideButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
                hideButton.layer.shadowRadius = 0
                hideButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
                hideButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
                horizontalSv.addArrangedSubview(hideButton)
                break
            }
            let button = SurveyButton()
            button.setTitle("\(buttonText[ i*column + j  ])",for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", size: 15)
            button.tag = i*column + j + 1
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCleaningKinds(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            horizontalSv.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
      
    
        stackView1.addArrangedSubview(horizontalSv)
    }
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(stackView1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach will mostly work.

If you want me to suggest a few changes, then:

1. Place `addButtonsToStackView()` inside an appropriate extension class (in your case `UIView`).
2. Use `buttonText` as a private property inside the class where you will use it.
3. Pass the `buttonText` properly into `addButtonsToStackView()` preferably as a parameter.